# Meu arquivo está ficando com a formatação de livro na segunda página

Tags: formatting

Boa noite, estou com um problema na formatação da página do Latex.

Mais especificamente no meu arquivo de introdução, onde a primeira página deste arquivo está configurada de maneira correta e respeitando as normas ABNT, **mas quando o texto vai para a segunda página desse arquivo, ela fica formatada no modelo de livros**, ignorando a formatação da primeira página que é a da abnt.

**Preciso que a segunda página desse arquivo fique com a mesma form matação da primeira página, mas como sou muito novato com o latex, não achei como ajustar isso.**

> GOOGLE TRANSLATE:
>
> Good night, I have a problem with the Latex page formatting.
>
> More specifically in my introduction file, where the first page of
>   this file is configured correctly and in compliance with ABNT
>   standards, but when the text goes to the second page of this file,
>   it is formatted in the book model, ignoring the formatting of the
>   first page which is the abnt.
>
> I need the second page of this file to have the same format as the first page, but as I am very new to latex, I didn't find how to adjust
>   it.

[image]

main:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openany, a4paper, english, brazil]{abntex2}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}      
\usepackage{graphicx,graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig,subfig}  
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}               
\usepackage{verbatim}               
\usepackage{tabularx}               
\usepackage{url}                    
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   

\include{extras/conf_citacoes}
\include{extras/dados}
\input{extras/conf_pdf}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
\onelineskip
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing


\pretextual
\include{pretextual/capa}
\input{pretextual/assinaturas}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage

\textual
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\include{caps/introducao}
\include{caps/justificativa}
\include{caps/problema}
\include{caps/objetivos}
\include{caps/fundamentacaoTeorica}
\include{caps/metodologia}
\include{caps/cronograma}
\include{caps/recursos}
\include{caps/anexos}
\include{caps/glossário}

\postextual
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. You have the twoside option enabled, which switches to a "book format".

Comment: The inner margin (right margin on even pages, left margin in odd pages) is  bigger with the `twoside` option to allow  bind the book without left a ridiculous inner margin. Use the package `geometry` to set margins according the thickness of your document.

Comment: @Fran Usually it is the reverse: the *outer* margin is wider than the inner margin. Binding is not a factor (with `geometry` one has the appropriate option).

Comment: unrelated but do not load  the `epsfig` package for any documents written since 1994, it is a legacy package for syntax used in the 1980s

Comment: do not use `\include` before `\begin{document}` (use `\input`)